# Simple strategy issue

Tags: pine-script

New to the forum, have done a search but not found my answer, new to pinescript.

I have coded a very simple strategy here, that is basically saying 'If the last 2 bars closed down then buy the next bar at the open and close/exit trade at the next close up bar'

I feel my script is close but I just can't seem to get it on the chart.

Any ideas what im missing to get this working?

many thanks

Apologies why the script is disjointed in a couple of places with huge gaps between words on a couple of lines, I had to go through every line on here and put 4 spaces before every line (do you have to do this every time?) some lines wouldn't let me.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at                         https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © elasticc

//@version=5
 strategy("s2",
 initial_capital=4000, 
 default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, 
 default_qty_value=100,
 overlay=true, 
 use_bar_magnifier=true)

//Get Inputs
CandlesBack         = input.int(title="No Of Bars Lookback", defval=2, step=1)
CandlesForward      = input.int(title="No of Bars Forward", defval=1, step=1)
i_time              = input.time(title="Date From", defval=timestamp("01 Jan              2020"))
i_time2             = input.time(title="Date To", defval=timestamp("01 Jan 2099"))

//Date Check filter
dateFilter          = time >= i_time and time <= i_time2


// Check buy/sell conditions
var float buyPrice  = 0
buycondition        = close < CandlesBack and strategy.position_size == 0 and        datefilter          
sellcondition       = CandlesForward > open and strategy.position_size >0 

// Enter Positions
if buycondition
strategy.entry(id="long", direction=strategy.long)
buyPrice := open

// Exit Positions    
if sellcondition
strategy.close(id="long", comment="Exit")
buyPrice := na

//Plot on chart
plot(buyPrice, color=color.green, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

Comment: Note: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

> If the last 2 bars closed down then buy the next bar at the open

Your script is not doing that, instead, you compare the closing price(`close`) of the candle with a constant integer(`CandlesBack` input), hence `close < CandlesBack`, is a comparison of a price with the input's default value of 2.

If you would like to compare the current candle with the previous ones, use the historical referencing operator `[]`:

`buycondition = close < close[CandlesBack] and strategy.position_size == 0 and dateFilter`

> close/exit trade at the next close up bar

Pine Script strategy places an order on the bar's close, once the close-up bar occurs, it will be executed on the next bar's open or the next real-time tick (if recalculation on every tick is enabled in the script)

`sellcondition = close > open and strategy.position_size >0`

You can find the explanation of the strategy order execution commands and examples in the manual - https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html

Comment: That would make sense. Thanks for that, appreciate it. Apologies too, didn't realise this was not a forum. Just read the link, will re-read again too. Thanks